# CFBundleDocumentTypes -- List my app in 'Photos'

Tags: ios, iphone, info.plist, cfbundledocumenttypes

I've setup my info.plist with the following info. My app is listed when you access a file from an email, but I want my app listed when someone is in their Photos App. Is there something else I need to do to be listed in the Photos app?

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MyApp</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.movie</string>
        </array>
        <key>NSExportableTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.movie</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

e.g. of what I want:

1. List item
2. User opens stock Photos app
3. Selects a video
4. Clicks the open/share button
5. I want my app listed here (next to Facebook, Vimeo, YouTube, etc.)

Comment: Did you had any luck with this?

Comment: No luck unfortunately. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah I have, but also no luck. It works in the Mail app and sadly not in the Photo app.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get listed in the Photos app, you need to implement a share extension.
[Docu](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html)